# How to have find-file's prompt match Emacs shell's $PWD?

Tags: emacs

With Emacs, if the current buffer is one that's "visiting" a normal file (for example), whose full pathname is `/path/to/somefile`, and one runs `find-file` (`C-x C-f`), the prompt that appears in the mini-buffer is something like

```
Find file: /path/to/▮
```

...with the cursor placed as indicated above by ▮.  IOW, the suggested path shown by default is always to the directory containing the file that the current buffer is visiting.

If, however, the current buffer is an Emacs *shell process*, and one runs `find-file`, then, AFAICT, the path shown in the prompt remains *fixed* at the value of `$PWD` *when the shell process was started*, irrespective of the *current* value of `$PWD`:

```
Find file: /pwd/at/startup/▮
```

This behavior is not so useful, because the `$PWD` at startup often becomes irrelevant later on.  It would be *really* nice if the directory shown in `find-file`'s prompt were instead the shell process's *current* `$PWD`.

Is there a simple way to modify `find-file` to behave this way whenever the current buffer is a shell process?

Comment: Emacs doesn't actually know what the shell's current working directory is, but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655782/

Answer (score 1):

You want "shell directory tracking".  E.g. check `dirtrack-mode` or `shell-dirtrack-mode`.

`shell-dirtrack-mode` tries to parse "cd" commands, (event_jr: which in my experience does not work consistently).  `dirtrack-mode` uses the prompt regexp, which works very well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to manage this.  As [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283394/stefan) notes, there are a couple of built in packages that manage it.

My preferred way is to alter your prompt (when in Emacs) to have the `$PWD` embedded in it, and then Emacs strips it out and uses it.  This has the benefit of always being up to date.  I've found that `dirtrack-mode` sometimes gets out of sync.

Check out my solution [here](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008_08_01_archive.html), which is a modification of a [similar implementation](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/ShellDirtrackByPrompt) on the Emacs Wiki.

Comment: Emacs comes with `dirtrack-mode` now.  **this is different to `shell-dirtrack-mode`.