# Open file from Emacs terminal without find-file

Tags: emacs, elisp, terminal-emulator

If I'm in a `term-mode` buffer and there is a file path displayed, how would I go about making the path "clickable", opening the file in a new buffer? It doesn't have to be mouse-clickable, in fact I'd prefer a key binding that works when the point is on the file path. Other than the common case of using `ls`, this function could be used when viewing a log file. Some debug info contains the file path and line number. Something like `lib/library.rb:34` for example. Ideally, Emacs could open a new buffer and move the cursor to line `34`.

Comment: Although not `term-mode`, `dired-mode` offers that feature:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dired-x/Find-File-At-Point.html  And here is something else that looks even more promising (i.e., `find-file-at-point` in `shell-mode`?):  https://snarfed.org/why_i_dont_run_shells_inside_emacs

Comment: Xah Lee has written something similar that skips the confirmation:  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_open_file_path_fast.html  Well, that's the general idea -- variations of find-file-at-point.

Comment: `find-file-at-point` seems to work with only complete paths. What about relative paths?

Comment: Zah Lee's doc-string says that his function offers that feature -- i.e., "*Input path can be {relative, full path, URL}.*"

Comment: I can't get the relative path to work. It says `file doesn't exist` and prompts to create one. Not sure how Emacs infers the base path.

Comment: Usually the base path is the path of (the file opened in) the current buffer. Try <kbd>M-x<kbd>`pwd`.

Comment: @ale what about a terminal? It would be helpful if Emacs' `pwd` mapped to the shell's `pwd`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13658751/439332 looks like it can keep Emacs' `pwd` synced.

Comment: Did you try `compilation-shell-minor-mode` ? (http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Shell#Make_file_paths_clickable) Also, I think using `ls` + a clic on the file is a wrong usage. It would be more emacsen (and featureful) to use `projectile`, open a dired buffer or simply find-file with ido.

Comment: @Ehvince I'm using a term, not a shell. Nevertheless, I tried that out and it made the term very slow and didn't make the paths clickable. I would be happy if I could open up a dired bufffer, projectile, or find-file.

Comment: @ReedG.Law i think the problem with using my function is that it grabs the :n as part of the file path. That's why it complains file doesn't exist. It's trivial to modify it so the path is grabbed and jump to line number though.

Comment: @ReedG.Law i edited the code so now it should do what you want.

Comment: @XahLee thank you! It works nicely with relative paths as well.

Comment: @XahLee I've been enjoying your `xah-open-file-at-cursor` for years now. There is one thing though. RSpec puts colons _after_ the `dir/file:pos` like so: `./spec/lib/twilio/services/validation_service_spec.rb:33:in `new'`. Your script seems to depend on spaces to delimit file paths. Is there a way to ignore the final colon?

Comment: Answering my own question: adding `(replace-regexp-in-string ":in$" ""  $inputStr)` fixes the problem.

Comment: @ReedG.Law great. I think i'd do the same. i wonder if i should ad it, is that convention used elsewhere? thanks.

Comment: @XahLee I'm not sure but at least anyone can Google it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: don't work against Emacs. Let Emacs work for you.

While you can use [`find-file-at-point`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/FFAP.html) or put together something yourself, you will be much better off running `make`, `grep` and other stuff which prints `"dir/file:pos"` using [<kbd>M-x compile</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) or [<kbd>M-x grep</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html).

- If you need to **interact** with your program which prints `"dir/file:pos"`, you can pass a prefix argument to `compile` and the compilation buffer will be interactive.
- If you have an **arbitrary** program whose output starts with `"dir/file:pos"`, e.g., `rails server`, all you need to do is run it as `(grep "rails server")`.

Comment: Good suggestion, and that's my normal workflow for using `ag`. But recently I've switched to running Rails and Java applications in `multi-term`s and I would love it if the debugging info could take me directly to the file and position.

Comment: Why are you using `term`? What is `ag`?

Comment: I just decided to make the switch to using a terminal emulator within Emacs rather than `gnome-terminal` so I could better integrate my editing workflow. `ag` is the silver searcher, similar to `grep`.

Comment: So all you need to do is `M-x grep` and then replace the `grep` in the command line with `ag`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. My main use case is to be able to quickly open paths in the form of `dir/file:pos` that are output by web applications run in a `multi-term`. I'm not sure how using `grep` relates to that. However, I did just think of a more Emacs-friendly way. Maybe I can pipe the output of `rails server` to another buffer that runs in a mode that highlights file paths such as `dired-mode` or `ag-mode`.

Comment: I found a package that does what I'm looking for for Rails: https://github.com/ananthakumaran/rails-log-mode

Comment: I didn't realize that `M-x compile` worked for things such as `lein run` or `rails server`. It seems a lot of things that I normally do within a shell can all be done in Emacs, such as renaming files through `dired`, managing git with `magit`, etc.